# Duplicate validations with EF CodeFirst & the DRY principle

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, validation, asp.net-web-api

Using EF CodeFirst, WebApi with DTOs and Angular (although the front end choice is immaterial):

I put the validation in my classes that generate the tables, such as the following `Required` attribute to ensure the column is not null:

```
[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

In WebApi, I use a DTO, so on the DTO model I have the exact same as the above, so that when the model binds I can check `ModelState.IsValid`.

Then I have the validation on the client side, which I am comfortable with.

Is this "best practice", or am I violating DRY principles with the first two?

---

#### Edit

So it looks like they're mostly for 2 different things: [1] is for generating the table (in CodeFirst), and [2] is for validating the input from the client.

For example, there's almost no point having a `Required` validation attribute on a `DateTime` field, because it will error trying to convert `null` to `DateTime` before the validation kicks in.

However, for strings, it's different: you need the `Required` attribute on the DB model for the `NOT NULL` field in the database, but you also want the `Required` attribute on the DTO string field otherwise it will pass validation and error when you save.

Comment: We stopped using this kind of validation on EF models as it mostly brings pain. Validation happens in DTO that you get from a client.. and once that is valid, your EF models will be valid as well, given that you only map DTO to EF-models with no extra processing. YMMV.

Comment: That depends on the access modifier of your classes. if you generate your model in EF as public, chances are that someone use those classes with out validation at all.

Comment: Is the *ONLY* way someone can insert into your database through a DTO? Can I not open a SQL client and run an INSERT? If you don't have validation at the data level as well as higher levels, I might be able to insert a NULL value into a field your application assumes can never be NULL.

Comment: @jmelosegui that opens a world of pain trying to decide which access modifiers to use! I tried a few internals but that broke a lot of other things. I need to get up to speed on those...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are violating DRY, because although you're using the same symbol in both classes, that symbol is used for different purposes in each class.

If you find that the DTOs you use in your data model are identical to those you use in your Web API controllers, there may be a case to be made for rationalising the two.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO Every layer in an application should check the validity of the data it is handled.

Did you also mark that property as not nullable column in your database right?

And No, you are not violating DRY principles.

Comment: Yep, definitely got in on the DB via the Required attribute on the CodeFirst model.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this solution to mimic a copy of attributes between models: http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-automap-asp-net-attribute-from-model-to-viewmodel.